# How can I iterate through a list of letters to assign float values to create a polynomial?

Tags: python, function, loops, input, polynomials

I am trying to integrate a polynomial function via the Trapezoidal Method (I can change to a more accurate method later). My code isn't perfect, and I'd like to understand exactly why it doesn't work. One problem I have is that the while loop does not end. My code thus far is as follows.

```
    def Integrate_Trapezoidal(x_LoBound,x_HiBound,N):
        """
        INPUT   :
                    x_LoBound   --      lower bound of integral
                    x_HiBound   --      upper bound of integral
                    N           --      number of slices (N --> inf ==> integral)
        OUTPUT  :
                                --      approximate value of integral
        """
        ## CREATE ALPHABET
        alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
        ## alphabet = ['a','b','c',...,'z'] ##
        ## WOULD LOVE TO TRY FLOATING INPUTS VIA ARRAY COMPREHENSION
        a = float(input("What is the coefficient of the lowest order term:  "))
        CoeffList = []
        CoeffNumList = []
        LengthCoeffList = [] ## [1,2,3,...,max] where max = coefficient of highest-order term
        for letter in alphabet:
            AddOne = int(1)
            AddOne += int(1)
            for i in range(int(1),int(AddOne)):
                letter = alphabet[int(i)]
                while letter in alphabet:
                    CoeffList.append(letter)
                    LengthCoeffList.append(len(CoeffList))
                    # alphabet[i]
                    # i = i + 1
                    letter = float(input("What is the coefficient of the next-order term:  ")) ## GO FROM a = ___ TO b = ___ TO c = ___ ...
                    CoeffNumList.append(letter)
                    if float(input("What is the coefficient of the next-order term:  ")) == '0':
                        print("Type 'Y for YES and 'N' for NO")
                        YESorNO = str(input("Is that the last term of the polynomial:  "))
                        endterm = YESorNO[-1] ## look at last character of string
                        if endterm == 'N' or endterm == 'n' or endterm == 'no' or endterm == 'NO' or endterm == 'No':
                            pass
                        elif endterm == 'Y' or endterm == 'y' or endterm == 'YES' or endterm == 'yes' or endterm == 'Yes':
                            break
                            def f(x):
                                """
                                INPUT   :
                                                   x    --  variable of function
                                                        EX: x = x_LoBound OR x = x_HiBound
                                OUTPUT  :
                                            function    --  f(x) = a x^0 + b x^1 + ...
                                                        EX: f(x_LoBound) OR f(x_HiBound)
                                """
                                for expval in LengthCoeffList and CoeffNum in CoeffNumList:
                                    # function = 0
                                    function += CoeffNum * x**expval
                                    return function
                    letter = alphabet[int(i+1)] ## GO FROM a TO b TO c ...
        ## TRAPEZOIDAL RULE
        # def f(x):
        #     return x**4 - 2*x + 1
        ht = (x_HiBound - x_LoBound) / N
        ss = 0.5 * f(x_LoBound) + 0.5 * f(x_HiBound)
        for num in range(1,N):
            ss += f(x_LoBound + num*ht)
        return ht*ss
    checkanswer = Integrate_Trapezoidal(0,2,10)
    print(checkanswer)
```

Comment: could you try to reduce that to a **minimal** version of this code that still reproduces your problem (just delete as much as you can; you want help on the code logic and not the algorithm itself). and do not define functions in loops!

Comment: I reduced the code before posting. If I reduce it further, then running the posted code will not recreate my problem.

The function is defined in the loop because it is based on the user input and is not pre-defined. The function in the loop takes values created from the loop. But if you know a better way, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: *The function is defined in the loop because it is based on the user input*: then the user input should be an argument of the function. and there is much you could strip down! as it is you are very unlikely to get someone have a look at your code (e.g.: should `Y` trigger a `break` from all your `for` loops? if that is the problem: forget about the `alphabet` and write an `for i in range(3)` loop and see if you can break out of that).

Comment: by the way: `float(input("What is the coefficient of the next-order term:  ")) == '0'` will never be `True`: you are comparing a `str` to a `float`.

Comment: At the end of the for loop, you pick the next letter with letter = alphabet[int(i+1)] ## GO FROM a TO b TO c ..., but don't actually change the stored value of I, so each time round it's the same. Does it help if you add i += 1 ?

Comment: I will have an opportunity to try this in a few hours. I will update accordingly.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I started the code anew from scratch. Your advice was helpful; I was going about the problem entirely wrong. The code simplifies a bit by going from the power of the highest order term to the lowest rather than visa-versa. I also tossed alphabet aside and am appending values into a list for coefficients and other values into a list of powers (of x as a polynomial). I see now that the function is better off not nested inside another function as well. That said, my first function can return an output that either contains 2 lists (coeffs and powers) or the output as a tuple.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Given this, I am having trouble extracting values element-wise (as a function of output[index] from both lists (coefficients and powers) into the function that outputs the polynomial. Do you know how to extract these elements in this manner? An approach for output[0] and output[1] OR the tuple approach would be appreciated. I can also zip the values into tuples if that helps.

Comment: @Guy I tried different variations of that but no dice. I reworked my approach (see comments above).

Comment: you'd have to post it as a new question. sorry, but without code i have no idea where you are at. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a go at looking over your code and found something that I think works, checking against a couple of college handouts I downloaded. As you have said in the comments, there were a lot of extra lists which aren't necessary, so I've cut back the code a lot there.

In particular, if the presumption if that each coefficient is added in sequence from lowest to highest order, and 0 is added for any that aren't there, all you need is the number of the element in the list to know the power of x.

I also moved the definition of `f()` to create the helper function `solve_point()` which works the same I think. In particular, `sum` and `enumerate` are built in, with `enumerate` iterating through `coeff_list` and also returning a count to give the power (0 upwards).

`get_coefficients()` was from your old `Integrate_Trapezoidal()` but more focused on just one thing - which is why it then returns `CoeffList` to be finally processed at the end.

```
def solve_point(x, coeff_list):
    return sum(coeff * x**e for e, coeff in enumerate(coeff_list))


def get_coefficients():
    CoeffList = []
    while True:
        # GO FROM a = ___ TO b = ___ TO c = ___ ...
        coeff = float(input("What is the coefficient of the next-order term:  "))
        CoeffList.append(coeff)
        if coeff == 0:
            YESorNO = raw_input("Is that the last term of the polynomial: [Y/N]  ")
            if YESorNO.upper() == 'Y':
                return CoeffList[:-1]

lo, hi, n = 0, 2, 6
coeff_list = get_coefficients()

ht = (hi - lo) / float(n)
ss = 0.5 * solve_point(lo, coeff_list) + 0.5 * solve_point(hi, coeff_list)
for num in range(1,n):
    ss += solve_point(lo + num*ht, coeff_list)
checkanswer = ht*ss


print(checkanswer)
```

I think its right - I have done a couple of checks. Hopefully it may be of help for your rewrite! If you have any examples that don't work, it would be good to know, or any errors you can see...

Comment: Seeing the input of a function obtained as the output of a different function is really helpful to a beginner like me. This is the most helpful thing I've come across on the site yet and I'm very grateful!

Comment: @mikey indeed, making small functions is very helpful to improve readability, and make everything easier to test.